# Yii cdbcriteria поиск в cgridview

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Здравствуйте!
Есть модель и таблица БД, в которой есть строка с датой, хранящейся в timestamp. В колонку даты при выводе cgridview я отдаю уже отформатированную дату таким образом:

```
  'value'=> Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd.MM.yyyy', $model->date),
```

Вопрос: как заставить поиск искать даты если вводить их в указанном выше формате (например 31.01.2013)?

Так же есть поле, в котором хранятся числа 0 и 1. В CGridview они выдаются таким образом:

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'status', array('0'=>'Активен', '1'=>'В архиве', ), array('style'=>'width:100px'));
```

При поиске я использую эту конструкцию, что бы осуществлялся поиск по словам Активен и В архиве:

```
 public $search_types = array("активен" => 0, "в архиве" => 1);

 $criteria->compare('status', !empty($this->status) ?
$this->search_types[$this->status] : array(), true);
```

Поиск работает корректно, но учитывается регистр (например Активен ищется, а активен уже нет). Логично предположить, что нужно использовать strtolower(), но не могу понят где именно.

Спасибо заранее всем, кто откликнется!

Answer (score 1):

**1. как заставить поиск искать даты если вводить их в указанном выше формате (например 31.01.2013)?**

если нужно конкретное сравнение, можно например вот так:

```
$criteria->compare('DATE_FORMAT(date_column, "%d.%m.%Y")', $this->date_column, true);
```

**2. Так же есть поле, в котором хранятся числа 0 и 1**

Попробуйте вот так сделать:

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'status', array('0'=>'Активен', '1'=>'В архиве', ), array('style'=>'width:100px'));

 $criteria->compare('status', $this->status, false);
```

Comment: 1. Не работает решение. Все так же не ищет дату.
2. Я так понимаю это решение позволит вводить в инпутах поиска cgridview 1 или 0, а мне надо, что бы можно было вводить слова "В архиве" и "Активен" при чем не должно быть разницы в каком регистре было введено слово.